# maven-jar-plugin file filterring

Tags: java, maven, maven-jar-plugin

I have a some perl file in my `src/main/java/com/pac/report.pl` which I want to package as part of my classes in the jar file.

Using maven `maven-jar-plugin` include directives, I have tried below and various other suggestions I pulled off the web, but doesn't copy the perl file as part of my classes in the jar file. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong.

```
<plugin>
 <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
     <include>**/*</include>
     </includes>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

**EDIT**

Also let me point out that I don't want to place the file in the resource directory due to legacy call and dependent reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the classes packaged into your *jar* aren't taken from *src*, but rather from target (specifically `/target/classes`), and the compiler completely ignores your non-java file.

Try placing your file in `src/main/resources/com/pac/report.pl` and it should be packaged into the jar (with the relative path of `/com/pac/report.pl`) since thats the default location where the resources plugin looks for additional files to add to /target before the jar plugin runs.

**EDIT** - or, if you dont want to / cant do this the way maven expects, you could manually [bind an execution of the resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) to the lifecycle to pick up your file and copy it over to target. something like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <phase>compile</phase> <!-- or later -->
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <!-- path to your *.pl file here -->
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
```